# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number on updating data in db

Tags: php, pdo

I'm kinda new in programming. I hope someone can help me with my problem. I'm trying to update my data but this error keeps popping out and i don't know what to do. here's my code

```
function updatePromo($name, $imageLocation, $dateRelease, $date){

    if(!isset($this->db))
        return new  Exception("Failed to update promo");

    $sql = "UPDATE  `promo` SET `name` = :name,
            `image_location` = :image_location,
            `date_release` = :date_release,
            `date` = :date WHERE `id` = :id";
    return $this->db->db_insert($sql, array(
            'name'=>$name,
            'image_location'=>$imageLocation,
            'date_release'=>$dateRelease,
            'date'=>$date
    ));
```

this is the code for updating data

```
$db = new PROMO_DAO();

$name = $_POST['updateName'];
$dateRelease = strtotime($_POST['updateDate'])*1000;
$date = $_POST['updateDate'];

$temp_dir = getTempUploadDir();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = $db->updatePromo($name, $temp_dir, $dateRelease, $date);

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result > 0) {
    $newId = $db->getLastInsertedId($name);

    $temp_target_file = $temp_dir . basename($_FILES["updateImage"]['name']);
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($temp_target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $newfilename = 'promo_' . $newId . '.' . $imageFileType;

    uploadImage($_FILES["updateImage"], $newfilename);

    $db->updateImageLocation($name, '/images/' . $newfilename);

    $response["status"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Promo updated successfully.";

} else {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to update Promo: " . $name);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one parameter and the colons, add them to the insert call like below

```
$sql = "UPDATE  `promo` SET `name` = :name,
            `image_location` = :image_location,
            `date_release` = :date_release,
            `date` = :date WHERE `id` = :id";
    return $this->db->db_insert($sql, array(
            ':name'=>$name,
            ':image_location'=>$imageLocation,
            ':date_release'=>$dateRelease,
            ':date'=>$date,
            ':id'=>$id
    ));
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, i somehow found the solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your array you have not added the `:` in the key as well as you have not passed the `:id` parameter as you are using it in your `WHERE` clause of the query.

Hope this will help you in solving your problem